# Applications of the fact that ideals in an integer ring are projective

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

Most texts on algebraic number theory include a proof that finitely-generated torsion-free ideals over a Dedekind Domain are projective. For example, Lang puts this in one of the very first chapters of his algebraic number theory book.

This is a soft question, but what are some applications of this fact in algebraic number theory? Perhaps I haven't gotten deep enough into the right theory, but I have seen this result stated many times in many places, but never actually used.

Can someone give a good example of a result with applications to the arithmetic of number fields where the fact that these ideals are projective is key to understanding the result?